# Error with multiple class inheritance Python

Tags: python, class, multiple-inheritance

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go # run "pip install plotly==4.9.0" in your terminal to install plotly
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import ast

eurusd = yf.Ticker("EURUSD=X")
usd_to_eur = 1 / (eurusd.info["ask"])
eur_to_usd = 1 * eurusd.info["ask"]

class Asset:
    def __init__(self,name, ticker, amount):
        self.amount = amount
        self.name = name
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.price = yf.Ticker(self.ticker).info["regularMarketPrice"]

class Usd_asset(Asset):
    def __init__(self, name, ticker, amount, buy_price):
        super().__init__(name, ticker, amount)
        self.buy_price = buy_price
        self.buy_price_eur = [x * usd_to_eur for x in self.buy_price]
        self.price_usd = yf.Ticker(self.ticker).info["regularMarketPrice"]
        self.price_eur = self.price_usd * usd_to_eur

class Crypto(Asset):
    def __init__(self, name, ticker, amount):
        super().__init__(name, ticker, amount)
        print("crypto")


class Crypto_Usd(Crypto, Usd_asset):
    def __init__(self, name, ticker, amount, buy_price):
        Usd_asset.__init__(self, name = name, ticker = ticker, amount = amount, buy_price = buy_price)
        Crypto.__init__(self, name = name, ticker = ticker, amount = amount)
        print("crypto usd")
```

Whenever I run it, I get the following:

```
Attribute Error: Type object 'Usd_asset' has no attribute '_Crypto_Usd__init'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

My goal is to have a class which inherits both from Crypto and from Usd_asset.
which in their turn both inherit from Asset.

Comment: share code as text please.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.8.6 I can't reproduce the error but I get an other strange behavior:

```
class Asset:
  def __init__(self, name):
    print("init Asset")
    self.name = name
class Usd_asset(Asset):
  def __init__(self, name):
    print("init Usd_asset")
    super().__init__(name)
    print("done Usd_asset")
class Crypto(Asset):
  def __init__(self, name):
    print("init Crypto", Crypto.__mro__)
    super().__init__(name)
    print("done Crypto")
class Crypto_Usd(Crypto, Usd_asset):
  def __init__(self, name):
    print("init Crypto_Usd")
    Usd_asset.__init__(self, name = name)
    Crypto.__init__(self, name = name)
    print("done Crypto_Usd")

print("\nCrypto('bar')")
x = Crypto('bar')
print("\nCrypto_Usd('foo')")
a = Crypto_Usd('foo')
```

The output:

```
Crypto('bar')
init Crypto (<class '__main__.Crypto'>, <class '__main__.Asset'>, <class 'object'>)
init Asset
done Crypto

Crypto_Usd('foo')
init Crypto_Usd
init Usd_asset
init Asset
done Usd_asset
init Crypto (<class '__main__.Crypto'>, <class '__main__.Asset'>, <class 'object'>)
init Usd_asset        ## <<<--- strange
init Asset
done Usd_asset
done Crypto
done Crypto_Usd
```

The problem is the calling of `Usd_asset.__init__()` inside the `Crypto.__init__()` method. The `__mro__` shows that `Asset` is the only super class.

With the full code I get an Exception in `Crypto.__init__()`

```
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'buy_price'
```

It tries to call `Usd_asset.__init__()`

#### Solution

Don't use `super()` in classes that are used in multiple inheritance. Or maybe never use `super()` because you don't know if the class will be used in multiple inheritance.

Always write the `Class.method(self, arguments)`

```
class Usd_asset(Asset):
    def __init__(self, name, ticker, amount, buy_price):
        Asset.__init__(self, name, ticker, amount)
        self.buy_price = buy_price
        self.buy_price_eur = [x * usd_to_eur for x in self.buy_price]
        self.price_usd = yf.Ticker(self.ticker).info["regularMarketPrice"]
        self.price_eur = self.price_usd * usd_to_eur

class Crypto(Asset):
    def __init__(self, name, ticker, amount):
        Asset.__init__(self, name, ticker, amount)
        print("crypto")
```

---

**Edit**

The reason `super()` in `Crypto.__init__()` chooses `Usd_asset.__init__()` is because `super()` or `super(Crypto, self)` uses `self.__class__.__mro__` to find the first parent class of `Crypto` class.

In case `self` is instance of `Crypto`

```
self.__class__.__mro__ (<class '__main__.Crypto'>, <class '__main__.Asset'>, <class 'object'>)
```

`Asset` will be chosen.

In case `self` is instance of `Crypto_Usd`

```
self.__class__.__mro__ (<class '__main__.Crypto_Usd'>, <class '__main__.Crypto'>, <class '__main__.Usd_asset'>, <class '__main__.Asset'>, <class 'object'>)
```

`Usd_asset` will be chosen.

```
class Crypto(Asset):
  def __init__(self, name):
    print("init Crypto", Crypto.__mro__)
    print("self.__class__.__mro__", self.__class__.__mro__)
    super().__init__(name)
    print("done Crypto")
```

The `__mro__` tuple does not show the multiple inheritance and thus creates this strange behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes a lot of sense and solved my problem!

Comment: @Krulke I found the cause of the `super()` problem, mark this as the answer if it is a solution for you

Answer (score 0):

because your instance is a *Crypto_Usd* when you use `super()` you do not get the classes *Asset* as you expected => replace the calls `super().__init(...)`by `Asset.__init__(self, ...)`

Answer (score -1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go # run "pip install plotly==4.9.0" in your terminal to install plotly
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import ast

eurusd = yf.Ticker("EURUSD=X")
usd_to_eur = 1 / (eurusd.info["ask"])
eur_to_usd = 1 * eurusd.info["ask"]

class Asset:
    def __init__(self,name, ticker, amount):
        self.amount = amount
        self.name = name
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.price = yf.Ticker(self.ticker).info["regularMarketPrice"]

class Usd_asset(Asset):
    def __init__(self, name, ticker, amount, buy_price):
        super().__init__(name, ticker, amount)
        self.buy_price = buy_price
        self.buy_price_eur = [x * usd_to_eur for x in self.buy_price]
        self.price_usd = yf.Ticker(self.ticker).info["regularMarketPrice"]
        self.price_eur = self.price_usd * usd_to_eur

class Crypto(Asset):
    def __init__(self, name, ticker, amount):
        super().__init__(name, ticker, amount)
        print("crypto")


class Crypto_Usd(Crypto, Usd_asset):
    def __init__(self, name, ticker, amount, buy_price):
        Usd_asset.__init__(self, name = name, ticker = ticker, amount = amount, buy_price = buy_price)
        Crypto.__init__(self, name = name, ticker = ticker, amount = amount)
        print("crypto usd")
```

Comment: is that an answer to your question or the code given as picture in your question ? in the second case edit your question to give that code and delete that answer (which is not an answer then) please

Comment: why import `numpy` twice? Why do you need `ast`?

Comment: numpy twice was a mistake, ast I need later on. Problem has been solved. thanks guys.

Comment: @Krulke please delete than non answer, next times edit your question rather than to wrongly use an answer